# Condense XML subsequent rows into parent Row

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012

I am having a quandary to resolve, with TSql.

Below is an example set of data that is riddled throughout log files.

I am working on a process of converting the "Valid" Contents into columns.  I can get every row, except the sole XML formatted rows, into Columns.  As described in the Problem section, it bugs out if not fully bombing out, when it comes to the rows with just XML Elements in them.

I have been able to isolate out the "invalid" rows out of the parser but then the row the data pertains to is irrelevant with out the subsequent information.

### Problem

The rows with `{DELIM}` in the Contents need to have the subsequent rows concatenated with it, to make a single row.

Example Data:

```
RowID                FileID               Contents
-------------------- -------------------- ---------
3595                 1                    8/30/2015 5:00:01 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
3596                 1                      <LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn>
3597                 1                      <ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded>
3598                 1                      <UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon>
3599                 1                      <ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs>
3600                 1                      <ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured>
3601                 1                      <ErrorString />
3602                 1                    </ImpersonationResultClass>
3629                 1                    8/30/2015 5:00:03 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
3630                 1                      <LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn>
3631                 1                      <ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded>
3632                 1                      <UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon>
3633                 1                      <ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs>
3634                 1                      <ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured>
3635                 1                      <ErrorString />
3636                 1                    </ImpersonationResultClass>
3653                 1                    8/30/2015 5:00:12 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
3654                 1                      <LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn>
3655                 1                      <ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded>
3656                 1                      <UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon>
3657                 1                      <ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs>
3658                 1                      <ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured>
3659                 1                      <ErrorString />
3660                 1                    </ImpersonationResultClass>
5239                 1                    8/30/2015 7:00:01 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
5240                 1                      <LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn>
5241                 1                      <ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded>
5242                 1                      <UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon>
5243                 1                      <ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs>
5244                 1                      <ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured>
5245                 1                      <ErrorString />
5246                 1                    </ImpersonationResultClass>
```

### Question

Could I get some help to compact the subsequent XML Elements into the single row with a valid DateTime?

For instance:

```
RowID                FileID               Contents
-------------------- -------------------- ---------
3595                 1                    8/30/2015 5:00:01 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn><ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded><UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon><ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs><ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured><ErrorString /></ImpersonationResultClass>
3629                 1                    8/30/2015 5:00:03 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn><ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded><UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon><ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs><ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured><ErrorString /></ImpersonationResultClass>
3653                 1                    8/30/2015 5:00:12 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn><ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded><UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon><ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs><ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured><ErrorString /></ImpersonationResultClass>
5239                 1                    8/30/2015 7:00:01 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn><ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded><UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon><ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs><ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured><ErrorString /></ImpersonationResultClass>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need this, it is probably not very efficient and there are probably better ways of doing it.

However you may have no other choices and here is a way of doing it.

> You data:

```
    declare @data table(RowID int, FileID int, Contents nvarchar(max))
    insert into @data(RowID, FileID, Contents) values
    (3595, 1, '8/30/2015 5:00:01 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">')
    , (3596, 1, '<LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn>')
    , (3597, 1, '<ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded>')
    , (3598, 1, '<UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon>')
    , (3599, 1, '<ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs>')
    , (3600, 1, '<ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured>')
    , (3601, 1, '<ErrorString />')
    , (3602, 1, '</ImpersonationResultClass>')
    , (3629, 1, '8/30/2015 5:00:03 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">')
    , (3630, 1, '<LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn>')
    , (3631, 1, '<ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded>')
    , (3632, 1, '<UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon>')
    , (3633, 1, '<ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs>')
    , (3634, 1, '<ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured>')
    , (3635, 1, '<ErrorString />')
    , (3636, 1, '</ImpersonationResultClass>')
    , (3653, 1, '8/30/2015 5:00:12 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">')
    , (3654, 1, '<LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn>')
    , (3655, 1, '<ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded>')
    , (3656, 1, '<UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon>')
    , (3657, 1, '<ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs>')
    , (3658, 1, '<ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured>')
    , (3659, 1, '<ErrorString />')
    , (3660, 1, '</ImpersonationResultClass>')
    , (5239, 1, '8/30/2015 7:00:01 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">')
    , (5240, 1, '<LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn>')
    , (5241, 1, '<ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded>')
    , (5242, 1, '<UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon>')
    , (5243, 1, '<ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs>')
    , (5244, 1, '<ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured>')
    , (5245, 1, '<ErrorString />')
    , (5246, 1, '</ImpersonationResultClass>');
```

> Query:

```
    with rows as(
        Select RowID, FileID, Contents
            , n = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by RowId)
        From @data 
        Where Contents like '%{DELIM}%'
    ), cat as (
        Select ID = r1.RowID, d.RowID, d.Contents From rows as r1
        Left Join rows as r2 on r1.n = r2.n - 1
        Left Join @data as d On d.RowID > r1.RowID and (d.RowID < r2.RowID or r2.RowID is null)
    )
    Select r.RowID, r.FileId
        , r.Contents+(
            Select c.Contents
            From cat as c
            Where c.ID = r.RowID 
            Order By c.RowID
            For XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    From rows r
```

> Another option:

```
    with rows as(
        Select RowID, FileID, Contents
            , n = Case When Contents like '%{DELIM}%' Then 
                    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by case when Contents like '%{DELIM}%' then 0 else 1 end order by RowId)
                Else  ROW_NUMBER() over(order by RowId) -
                    ROW_NUMBER() over(order by case when Contents like '%{DELIM}%' then 1 else 0 end, RowId)
                End
        From @data 
    )
    Select r.RowID, r.FileId
        , FIRST_VALUE(Contents) Over(partition by n order by RowId) + (
            Select r2.Contents
            From rows as r2
            Where r.n = r2.n and Contents not like '%{DELIM}%'
            Order By r2.RowID
            For XML PATH (''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'varchar(max)')
    From rows as r
    Where r.Contents like '%{DELIM}%'
    Order By RowID
```

> Output:

```
    RowID  FileId  Contents
    3595   1       8/30/2015 5:00:01 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn><ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded><UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon><ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs><ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured><ErrorString /></ImpersonationResultClass>
    3629   1       8/30/2015 5:00:03 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn><ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded><UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon><ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs><ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured><ErrorString /></ImpersonationResultClass>
    3653   1       8/30/2015 5:00:12 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn><ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded><UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon><ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs><ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured><ErrorString /></ImpersonationResultClass>
    5239   1       8/30/2015 7:00:01 AM{DELIM}Debug{DELIM}Impersonation result 1: <ImpersonationResultClass xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><LoggedOn>true</LoggedOn><ProfileLoaded>false</ProfileLoaded><UsingLocalLogon>false</UsingLocalLogon><ImpersonatedAs>NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM</ImpersonatedAs><ErrorOccured>false</ErrorOccured><ErrorString /></ImpersonationResultClass>
```

Comment: In short I have a log I going to be cataloging into SQL.  Unfortunately, I do not have access to the logging methodology (3rd party software).  80% of the log file is a 1 row entry; in some cases, it has a well-formed XML format entry that spans multiple rows of data.  Going to split the RawData into two tables, one to parse single-entry rows and the other for XML data.

Comment: Did my answer help you?